# Glassfish stops responding after few days

Tags: glassfish

I have an EJB application consisting of few modules (core, REST, 2x JSF, ...) deployed on Glassfish. After few days whole application stops working. Glassfish accepts connections but response is never returned.

The load is not high. When this happens the consume of CPU of glassfish is low, memory is in normal. The only thing I can see is increasing number of threads (hundreds). I think that is because of the connections which are accepted by glassfish and kept until timeout.

Unfortunately this happens only on production server. Glassfish admin is working. When we restart the glassfish everything works ok for another few days.

Glassfish 3.1.2,
Ubuntu 12.04

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi! Did you handle it ? We have exact same symptoms and no idea whats going on.